# How Can I Prevent Template Generation for Objects That Don't Implement a Method

Tags: c++, templates, methods, lambda, metaprogramming

So for the purpose of example let's say I have 3 simple `struct`s, the second of which doesn't contain a `bar` method:

```
struct one {
    void foo(const int);
    void bar();
};

struct two {
    void foo(const int);
};

struct three {
    void foo(const int);
    void bar();
};
```

Then I have a `struct` which will manage objects of these types:

```
struct owner {
    map<int, one> ones;
    map<int, two> twos;
    map<int, three> threes;

    template <typename T, typename Func>
    void callFunc(T& param, const Func& func) {
        func(param);
    }

    template <typename T>
    void findObject(int key, const T& func) {
        if(ones.count(key) != 0U) {
            callFunc(ones[key], func);
        } else if(twos.count(key) != 0U) {
            callFunc(twos[key], func);
        } else {
            callFunc(threes[key], func);
        }
    }

    void foo(const int key, const int param) { findObject(key, [&](auto& value) { value.foo(param); } ); }
    void bar(const int key) { findObject(key, [&](auto& value) { value.bar(); } ); }
};
```

When I try to compile this I get:

> error: `struct two` has no member named `bar`

Is there a way that I can work around this?

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/V6sU39)

Comment: so...what do you expect to do if you found the key in `twos`?

Comment: What *should* happen if there is no "`bar`" to use?

Comment: T.C.'s answer is the right solution, but for a very direct fix to what is literally here [this works](https://pastebin.com/ZTHvXuE1)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, the utilities. One is our favorite `overload` that shows off three C++17 features, and overloads the `operator()` of several function objects, all in two lines.

```
template<class... Ts> struct overload : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overload(Ts...) -> overload<Ts...>;
```

Then an accepts-everything fallback tag type:

```
struct fallback_t { template<class T> fallback_t(T&&) {} };
```

Now to the call itself. We make the original generic lambda SFINAE-friendly by putting the `value.bar()` call into the trailing return type, then overload it with a fallback overload that has undefined behavior if actually invoked (since OP "omit[ted] any explicit definition of behavior"):

```
void bar(const int key) { 
    findObject(key, overload {
          [&](auto& value) -> decltype(void(value.bar())) { value.bar(); },
          [](fallback_t){ fire_missiles_and_impregnate_cat(); }
    } ); 
}
```

Comment: I am fine with missiles, but the cat!

Comment: I like this, but I'm sure OP would appreciate an explanation of why this works.

Comment: Should your second line use `auto`?

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde: It would be ambiguous when `bar()` exists.

Comment: OK, I want to accept this, but I'm kinda against accepting code only answers. I actually see what you're doing here but the next person may not. Could you just give one sentence of explanation?

Comment: Well this is annoying :( It doesn't work in Visual Studio. I've asked a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48870308/2642059 Is there any hope for a workaround?

Comment: *"fallback overload that has undefined behavior"* I would prefer to say implementation specific ;-)

Comment: You wrap `value.bar()` in `void`... why? What's going on there, my actual `bar` needs to return a value but I cannot here.

Comment: `template<class... Ts> overload(Ts...) -> overload<Ts...>;` What is this, syntactically? Looks like a function declaration to me with a trailing return type. But that requires an `auto` in front of the function name, so I think I'm missing something here.

Comment: @JonathanMee Your lambda returns `void`; I'm just following suit. There's no particular reason for the cast otherwise.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde That's a deduction guide.

Comment: @T.C. So adding in return types like this: https://ideone.com/q6b7Y4 you can see me floundering on the line: `[&](auto& value) -> decltype(void(value.bar())) { value.bar(); }` I'm having trouble creating something there that won't default everything to return void.

Comment: @T.C. Cool, thanks! I forgot that c++17 introduced this convenience for templates.

Comment: @JonathanMee that's your `foo` lambda still returning `void`.

Comment: @T.C. Thank you T.T

Comment: @T.C. OK, while you were right on that, but even when I correct that, it always opts for the fallback, even when a good function is available.

Comment: @T.C. Welp, I'm stuck again thought I'd link you to the latest hoop that I can't figure out how to jump through on this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49057387/2642059