# How to Support Variadic Template Types in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, metaprogramming

[T.C. gave a clever solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48835768/2642059) which used this object:

```
template<class... Ts> struct overload : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overload(Ts...) -> overload<Ts...>;
struct fallback_t { template<class T> fallback_t(T&&) {} };
```

Unfortunately I can't get that to compile in Visual Studio 2017. I get the errors:

> 1> warning C4346: 'Ts::()': dependent name is not a type 
>   1> note: prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type 
>   1> note: see reference to class template instantiation 'owner::overload'  being compiled 
>   1> error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '...' 
>   1> error C2059: syntax error: '...' 
>   1> error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';' 
>   1> error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition 
>   1> error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '...' 
>   1> error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '...' 
>   1> error C2365: 'Ts': redefinition; previous definition was 'template parameter' 
>   1> note: see declaration of 'Ts' 
>   1> error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';' 
>   1> error C2059: syntax error: '...' 
>   1> error C2059: syntax error: ')' 
>   1> error C2955: 'owner::overload': use of class template requires template  argument list 
>   1> note: see declaration of 'owner::overload' 
>   1> error C2664: 'void owner::bar:: 
> ::operator ()(owner::fallback_t) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'owner::fallback_t' to 'owner::fallback_t' 
>   1> note: use of undefined type 'owner::fallback_t' 
>   1> note: see declaration of 'owner::fallback_t' 
>   1> error C2672: 'owner::findObject': no matching overloaded function found 
>   1> error C2780: 'void owner::findObject(int,const T &)': expects 2 arguments - 1  provided 
>   1> note: see declaration of 'owner::findObject'

Is there any trickery that I can do to make Visual Studio respect the variadic template in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to compile in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) mode with `/std::c++17` as @S.M. has noted; note that some C++17 features can break existing code.  In addition as @milesbudnek has noted, as of today MSVC doesn't support the requried features.

If you cannot use C++17 mode you can implement this in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32476942/1774667).

I'd make a few changes:

```
template <class... Fs>
struct overload_t;

// zero
template<>
struct overload_t<> {};

// >1
template <class F0, class... Frest>
struct overload_t<F0, Frest...> :
  F0,
  overload_t<Frest...>
{
    overload_t(F0 f0, Frest... rest) :
      F0(std::move(f0)), overload_t<Frest...>(std::move(rest)...)
   {}

    using F0::operator();
    using overload_t<Frest...>::operator();
};

// 1
template <class F0>
struct overload_t<F0> : F0
{
    overload_t(F0 f0) : F0(std::move(f0)) {}

    using F0::operator();
};

template <class... Fs>
auto overload(Fs... fs)
{
  return overload_t<Fs...>(std::move(fs)...);
}
```

Comment: @Jarod42 Good point; it is redundant with the single-argument specialziation (which I ususally don't write)

Comment: So if I remove the "zero" template and fix the ctor intialization list it will compile but still only gives me the fallback lambda: https://ideone.com/q6b7Y4

Comment: @JonathanMee What is `fooint`?!  Anyhow, I deleted a bunch of code that didn't seem to do anything useful and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

It is valid in C++17 only. Try to compile it in Visual Studio 2017 with the flag `/std:c++17` under Project -> Properties -> C++ -> Language. Please note, C++17 is available starting from Visual Studio 2017.3.

Answer (score 2):

This is dependent on three separate C++17 features:

- variadic using-declarations (that support pack expansion)
- aggregates with base classes
- class template argument deduction

The usual pre-C++17 workaround for the first is recursive inheritance (forwarding omitted for simplicity):

```
template<class T, class... Ts> 
struct overload : T, overload<Ts...> {
    using T::operator();
    using overload<Ts...>::operator();
    overload(T t, Ts... ts) : T(t), overload<Ts...>(ts...) {}
};

template<class T> 
struct overload<T> : T {
    using T::operator();
    overload(T t) : T(t) {}
};

template<class...Ts> 
overload<Ts...> make_overload(Ts... ts) {
    return overload<Ts...>(ts...); 
}
```

The constructors are needed if the compiler doesn't support aggregates with base classes; the `make_overload` is needed if the compiler doesn't support template argument deduction for class templates.

Comment: Worth noting that as of the time of this question's asking, VisualStudio 2017 [does not support any of those three features](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/12/19/c17-progress-in-vs-2017-15-5-and-15-6/), even with `/std:c++17`.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit further, I'm not certain what you mean there.

Comment: Ah you're saying my lambda argument being const found it.

Answer (score 1):

In C++14, it would be something like:

```
template <typename ... Ts> struct overload;

template <typename T>
struct overload<T> : T
{
    template <typename U>
    overload(U&& u) : T(std::forward<U>(u)) {}

    using T::operator();
};


template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct overload<T, Ts...> : overload<T>, overload<Ts...>
{
    template <typename U, typename ... Us>
    overload(U&& arg, Us&&... args) : overload<T>(std::forward<U>(arg)),
                                      overload<Ts...>(std::forward<Us>(args)...) {}

    using overload<T>::operator();
    using overload<Ts...>::operator();
};

template<class... Ts>
overload<std::decay_t<Ts>...> make_overload(Ts&&... args)
{
    return {std::forward<Ts>(args)...};
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62ec5145db345fde)

Comment: So in the return here... All these functions (`foo` and `bar` return `int`s) is there a way to pipe that through? it seems like the operator return type between `overload<T>` and `overload<Ts...>` creates something of a problem.

Comment: @JonathanMee: Your issue is const correctness: [Demo](https://ideone.com/9hx9YZ).